# Different cell sizes with an collectionView based on constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created a collectionView where i have 3 cells the first cells has to fill first row and the third should fill second row however i can't seem to figure out how to do this, since everytime i try to do in `sizeForItemAt` i get that the collectionView frame is `(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Here is what i have at the moment

```
class FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var numberOfCells: Int!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupLayout()
    }

    func setupLayout() {
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        minimumLineSpacing = 1

    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        set {

        }
        get {
            let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 2

            let itemWidth = (self.collectionView!.frame.width - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns
            let itemHeight = self.collectionView!.frame.height / 2


            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        }
    }


}
```

illustration of what i want

setting up collectionView in my view

```
func createCollectionView() {
    let layout = FlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.numberOfCells = 2



    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.topWrapperView.addSubview(collectionView)


    collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

        make.left.equalTo(topWrapperView).offset(0)
        make.top.equalTo(topWrapperView).offset(0)
        make.bottom.equalTo(topWrapperView).offset(0)
        make.right.equalTo(topWrapperView).offset(0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation except it was the first cell that I wanted 2 cells in first row, with 3 each row after. Used it for a main profile pic and bio in a collection view of images. I successfully implemented it using sizeForItemAtIndexPath with default UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. 
Here is something that should work for your situation:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

let insets = collectionView.contentInset
let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width - (insets.left + insets.right + 1)
let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom)

  switch indexPath.row {
   case 0, 1:

   return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 2, height: collectionViewHeight / 2)

    default:
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewHeight / 2)
  }
}
```

You can change what you divide height by to get desired height.

This is what I wrote for my situation, figured I'd post it incase it can help you or anyone else who reads it. If you want it to change with rotation, use viewWillTransition and set a bool flag with a didSet listener:

```
 var isPortraitOrientation: Bool = true {
   didSet {
 if oldValue != isPortraitOrientation {
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
     }
   }
} 

 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
  isPortraitOrientation = (size.width - size.height) <= 0 ? true : false
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width - (insets.left + insets.right + 1)
    let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom)

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:

        if textViewSelected {
            return isPortraitOrientation ? CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewHeight / 2) : CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewWidth / 3)
        } else {
            return isPortraitOrientation ? CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 2, height: collectionViewWidth / 2) : CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 2, height: collectionViewHeight / 1.5)
        }
    case 1:
        return isPortraitOrientation ? CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 2, height: collectionViewWidth / 2) : CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 2, height: collectionViewHeight / 1.5)

    default:
        return isPortraitOrientation ? CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 3, height: collectionViewWidth / 3) : CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth / 5, height: collectionViewWidth / 5)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

based on your additional code, instead of doing CGRect.zero for the collectionView frame use topWrapperView.bounds.

Comment: however as i mentioned my collectionView is set based on autolayout and therefore if i hadd your code it will return `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` for the collectionViewWidth

Comment: I just added a collectionView using auto layout and was able to print width in viewDidLoad. If anything, invalidate the collectionViewlayout in viewDidLayoutSubviews, by then the collection view should have constraints set up.

Comment: i've addded my collectionView code and constraints. its just random that it works in `override var itemSize: CGSize` where it gets correct collectionView values but not in`sizeForItemAt`

Comment: worked like a charm final thing can i change `minimumInteritemSpacing` so it isnt on the second row since it looks like a weird that there is spacing on the second row?

Comment: glad it worked. I'm really not sure so I can't give you an answer on that. That's something I would need to test out before I make a fool of myself and try to give you an answer. I know you can change spacing per section, but I don't know if its possible per row.

Comment: Save the day, mate! Cheers!